# ширина owl-carousel2

Tags: html

Использую слайдер owl carousel 2, и никак не могу понять как изменить размеры слайдера, вернее высота меняется если менять её у класса owl-item, а ширина в том же классе не меняется, а мне нужно чтобы у слайдера на странице была определенная ширина.

```
.owl-item {
    width: 100px;
    height: 300px;

}
```

Comment: установите необходимую ширину для owl-carousel

Comment: .owl-carousel{
   width: 200px
}
пробовал так, все равно ничего не меняется

Comment: Пример https://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/g91um28f/